# Why cannot ftp.retrbinary work with file context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

I am downloading a binary file via ftp, and it works:

```
        target = open(my_file, mode='wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + my_file, target.write)
        target.close()
```

However, when I am trying to improve my code, using a context manager, it creates a zero length file, and fails to download the contents:

```
        with open(my_file, mode='wb') as target:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + my_file, target.write)
```

What is wrong with my attempt to use a context manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that nothing is wrong with your attempt to use a context manager.

I used your exact code (filling in a site and file name) to download a file from a public ftp site (below).  Give it a try.

You likely changed something else (that you haven't shown us), when you changed your code to use a context manager.

```
import ftplib

def main():

    ftp = ftplib.FTP("speedtest.tele2.net", user='anonymous', passwd='anonymous')
    my_file = "5MB.zip"

    with open(my_file, mode='wb') as target:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + my_file, target.write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be an intermittent problem with my ftp server, not a Python problem.